# Cannot set path for JAVA (Kotlin could not find the required JDK)

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, java-8

I've literally tried everything I can think of. When running **flutter run**, I get:

```
Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

I've tried setting my path in terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

**echo $JAVA_HOME** gives me this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

I've tried adding it to the end of /etc/environment. I've tried to re-install java. Any ideas? I'm banging my head against a wall.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install a JDK, or a JRE?

Comment: JDK. I made sure of it. sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: Did you add it to your path?

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea which file I need to add it to. Which file? In the bashrc file?

Comment: Sorry for double post, but i added export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 in ~/.bashrc

Comment: Go through something like https://medium.com/@rohancbandara/install-openjdk-and-set-java-home-path-in-ubuntu-2ce2bc3a8fb2 first.

Comment: Yup, done that :(

Comment: Install JDK from snap or choco. They will set the environmental variable themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda think I figured it out, but not entirely sure. I restarted my PC, and now it seems to work. This could be due to 2 reasons:

The .bashrc file edit doesn't work after you added your path until you restart, or:
Visual Studio Code needed a restart, I couldn't say

Comment: Just adding it to a shell startup script is insufficient, you need it on your *current* path, either by doing it manually, `source`ing the startup script, opening a new terminal, or... restarting if you have the time. Editing a file doesn’t mean you’ve edited your environment :)

Comment: Gotcha. I apologize, when it comes to Linux I'm not too familiar with stuff like this. Thanks for your help, Dave!

Comment: No worries! It's a process.